# Transform multiple CSV rows in Pandas into one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm just starting out with Pandas and I'm trying to make a data file I have into something I can export and read. The CSV I have is in this form:

```
time    |   parameter   |   value
------------------------------------
1       |       a       |   21
2       |       a       |   21
3       |       a       |   21
1       |       b       |   19
2       |       b       |   19
3       |       b       |   19
1       |       c       |   17
2       |       c       |   17
3       |       c       |   17
```

I want to transform it in the following form:

```
time    |   a   |   b   |   c   
------------------------------------
1       |   21  |   19  |   17  
2       |   21  |   19  |   17  
3       |   21  |   19  |   17  
1       |   21  |   19  |   17  
2       |   21  |   19  |   17  
3       |   21  |   19  |   17  
1       |   21  |   19  |   17  
2       |   21  |   19  |   17  
3       |   21  |   19  |   17
```

Of course my data have different values, but the example above should be sufficient. It's weather data, like temperature and wind speed, and each row has the timestamp of the measurement, the param name and the value.

I want to transform it into a single row with 3 columns (or more if there are more parameters) for each timestamp, where the column name is the param name.

I know that I have to group my data by the time column so I've done
`df.groupby('time')`

However, I cannot figure out how to execute an apply method that will give me the results I want. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: why not just do `df.pivot(index='time', columns='parameter')['value']`

Comment: Thank you @Chris. It gives me the error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. Should I group by the time first?

Comment: then i am guessing your actual dataframe is different from your example: in your actual dataframe you probably have two or more rows with the same`time` and `parameter` values. Is that correct?

Comment: It is a big dataset downloaded from satellite data, so maybe there are duplicates. Is there a quick way to figure it out?

Comment: Yes try `df[df[['time', 'parameter']].duplicated(keep=False)]` and see if anything is returned. This will show you duplicated rows for `time` and `parameter`

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working with pivot_table, and an aggfunc. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='time', columns='parameter', values='value')
```

```
parameter   a   b   c
time                 
1          21  19  17
2          21  19  17
3          21  19  17
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that there was a single function for doing what I needed. `pivot_table` worked in my case since I had duplicate values in the dataset, where the normal `pivot` did not.